# log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, log4j, eclipse-rcp

While loading log4j from within Eclipse plugin (in forced programmatic mode) it says it can't find root logger information, while it presents.

The SSCCE code is below. It is based on simplest available headless RCP application sample:

```
package try_eclipsepluginlog4j_01;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;


/**
 * This class controls all aspects of the application's execution
 */
public class Application implements IApplication {

    static
    {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Try_EclipsePluginLog4j_01");
            URL config1 = bundle.getEntry("/conf/log4j.sample.xml");
            URL config2 = FileLocator.resolve(config1);
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(config2);

            org.apache.log4j.Logger log4j = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

            log4j.info("log4j is here");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext)
     */
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello RCP World!");
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#stop()
     */
    public void stop() {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

Configuration file is follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Output follows:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@58242ff4.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@547248ad[Try_EclipsePluginLog4j_01:1.0.0.qualifier(id=13)] class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder@58242ff4.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@547248ad[Try_EclipsePluginLog4j_01:1.0.0.qualifier(id=13)] class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/eclipse-rcp-kepler/Try_EclipsePluginLog4j_01/conf/log4j.sample.xml
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (try_eclipsepluginlog4j_01.Application).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hello RCP World!
```

Project structure is follows:

[image]

Comment: There's a catch block swallowing an `IOException` in the static initializer. Are you able to add `e.printStackTrace()` here - or check with the debugger that the code is not falling into this catch block?

Comment: No, it is not falling there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using an XML file and not a properties file, try using the `DOMConfigurator` rather than the `PropertyConfigurator`.

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(config2);
```